# Intuition about Herbrand Models.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I'm having trouble understanding how Herbrand models work. I feel like there is a bigger picture to it which I'm not understanding.

Why does every satisfiable first order formula have a herbrand model at all ? Can I somehow construct a Herbrand model from a normal model ?

My book also says that : a formula is unsatisfiable iff the Herbrand expansion is unsatisfiable. The book I'm using "Mathematical Logic for computer science by Mordechai Ben-Ari" has all the proofs of the above but its not very intuitive to me.

Could somebody share their point of view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a nutshell, an [Herbrand structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure#Definition) is a mathematical structure built with the syntactical stuff: *terms* are used as objects of the domain of the interpretation.

Herbrand's proof procedure is a way to reduce the compelxity of first-order logic to propositional calculus, replacing quantified formulas with [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)).

We consider a *theory* $T$ (a set of formulas) and we transform it in a set $S$ of clauses.

We use the constants of the theory (or an arbitrary one $a$, if no constant at all is used: this amounts to the assumption of "standard" FOL semantics about interpretations with non-empty domain) to build up the *H-universe* (the domain made of syntactical stuff) using the function symbols of the theory to generate all the terms.

Example: if the theory (in clause form) is $S = \{ P(a), ¬P(x) ∨ P(f(a)) \}$, the *H-universe* will be: $H = \{ a,f(a),f(f(a)), \ldots \}$.

If neither constants nor function symbols are used, e.g. $S = \{ P(x), ¬P(x) ∨ P(y) \}$, the *H-universe* will be $H = \{ a \}$.

Terms without variables ("closed" terms), like $a$ and $f(a)$ above, are called *ground terms*.

Having the domain $H$, we build the *interpretation*: constants are interpreted with themselves, and function are interpreted as mapping from *ground terms* to *ground terms*.

Predicates are interpreted through *ground instances* obtained from clauses replacing variables with ground terms.

Let $S = \{ P(x), ¬P(x) ∨ P(f(a)) \}$; again we have $H = \{ a,f(a),\ldots \}$. The ground instances for clause $P(x)$ are: $P(a), P(f(a)), \ldots$.

The key result is:

> A set of clauses $S$ is *unsatisfiable* iff $S$ is false under all the *H-interpretations*.

The first part of the theorem is obvious: if a set of formulas is false under **all** interpretations, it will be false also under the subset of the *H-interpretations*.

The non-trivial part is proved using an auxiliary *Lemma*:

> Given an interpretation $I$ over some domain $D$ that satisfy a set of clauses $S$, we cam build a corresponding *H-interpretation* $I_H$ that also satisfy $S$.

The *H-interpretation* $I_H$ is manufactured from the domain $D$ mapping *ground terms* $h_i \in H$ to elements $d_i \in D$ and using *gound instances*:

> $P^{I_H}(h_1, \ldots h_n)=$ **T(F)** iff $P^I(d_1, \ldots, d_n)=$ **T(F)**.

Having the *Lemma* above, the proof of the last part of H's theorem is straightforward: assume that the set of clauses $S$ is false under all *H-interpretation* and assume that $S$ is satisfiable (i.e. **not** unsatisfiable).

Then there is an interpretation $I$ with domain $D$ such that $S$ is true in $I$.

By the *Lemma* we can build an *H-interpretation* $I_H$ corresponding to $I$ such that $S$ is true under $I_H$.

But this contradicts the assumption that $S$ is false under all *H-interpretations*.

*Conclusion*: $S$ must be *unsatisfiable*.