# First Order Logic - Classic Interpretations vs Herbrand interpretations

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have a formula in first order logic.
I was teach the standard pre-interpretation followed by a interpretation.

Now, i have studied the Herbrand interpretation. 
My prof. told me that the Herbrand interpretations are a smaller number respect the set of standard interpretations.
But why ?

Comment: You can see the post: [intuition-about-herbrand-models](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468277/intuition-about-herbrand-models)

Comment: You can see also [Herbrand Semantics](http://logic.stanford.edu/herbrand/herbrand.html) and [Logic programming](http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/8710/f03/ch2.pdf).