# Herbrand Theorem and Clauses

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I've just studied the Herbrand Theorem. I also used this fantastic explanation [Intuition about Herbrand Models.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468277/intuition-about-herbrand-models) .

What i dont understand, is why Herbrand's Theorem only applies to a set of **clauses**, and not to other sentences ?

Comment: See [Resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_resolution_technique) : every set of formulas can be rewritten as a set of clauses. "The resolution technique uses proof by contradiction and is based on the fact that any sentence in propositional logic can be transformed into an equivalent sentence in conjunctive normal form."

Comment: Hi Mauro, why cant i use resolution rule directly to sentences that are not clauses ?

Comment: You can try with a good textbook, like e.g. M.Fitting, [First-Order Logic and Automated Theorem Proving](https://books.google.it/books?id=eaXbBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover). :-)

Comment: See also [Resolution for FOL](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4700/2011fa/lectures/16_FirstOrderLogic.pdf).